# Нужно центрировать блок a внутри div

Tags: css

Здравствуйте. Я делаю сайт и не могу понять, как можно центрировать элементы `a` внутри `div`. Подскажите. Заранее спасибо.

[image: ссылка меню]

Код:

```css
.hmenu {
  margin-left:8%;
  width:1200px;
  background-color:#119EDA;
  height:110px;
  }

.ar  {
  background-color:#119EDA;
  float:left;
  width:200px; 
  height:44px;
  background-image:url(http://pro-okis.ru/file/pro-okis_ru/button/button2.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  top:20px;
}

a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  margin-top:10px;
  font-family:verdana;
  font-size:14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hmenu">
  <div class="ar"><a href="">Главное меню</a></div>
  <div class="ar"><a href="">Форум</a></div>
  <div class="ar"><a href="">Мобильная связь</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: А можно увидеть `html` код? `.hmenu` или `.ar` является родительским div`ом?

Comment: @Dmitriy Сделайте, пожалуйста, *запускаемый* код.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, судя по цветам, которые указаны в CSS: `.hmenu` - меню, `.ar` - пункт (собственно наш div), `a` - понятно что

Comment: А как сделать код запускаемым ?

Comment: HTML код снизу, сразу после скобки

Answer (score 6):

Для **родительского** *div'a* ставите `position:relative`.

И к элементу, который нужно отцентрировать внутри него применяете следующий стиль:

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Таким образом можно центрировать **все** внутри контейнеров с `position: relative`.

P.S. Вроде бы можно так центрировать и в блоках с `absolute` или `fixed`.

Answer (score 4):

Центрировать можно с помощью: `line-height`, отступов, таблиц, `transform`, псевдоэлемента, `flexbox`, внутри элемента button:

Пример с псевдоэлементом - https://jsfiddle.net/fdwqdkya/

```css
.hmenu {
      margin-left:8%;
      width:1200px;
      background-color:#119EDA;
      height:110px;
      }

    .ar  {
      background-color:#119EDA;
      float:left;
      width:200px; 
      height:44px;
      background-image:url(http://pro-okis.ru/file/pro-okis_ru/button/button2.png);
      background-size: 100% 100%;
      background-repeat:no-repeat;
      top:20px;
      display: table;
      text-align: center;
    }

    a {
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: middle;
      text-decoration:none;
      color:#FFFFFF;
      margin-top:10px;
      font-family:verdana;
      font-size:14px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="hmenu">
  <div class="ar"><a href="">Главное меню</a></div>
  <div class="ar"><a href="">Форум</a></div>
  <div class="ar"><a href="">Мобильная связь</a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```css
.hmenu {
  margin-left:8%;
  width:1200px;
  background-color:#119EDA;
  height:110px;
  }

.ar  {
  background-color:#119EDA;
  float:left;
  width:200px; 
  height:44px;
  background-image:url(http://pro-okis.ru/file/pro-okis_ru/button/button2.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  top:20px;
  text-align: center; /* Центрируем по горизонтале */
}

a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  margin-top:10px;
  font-family:verdana;
  font-size:14px;
  line-height: 44px; /* Центрируем по вертикале */
}
```

```html
<div class="hmenu">
  <div class="ar"><a href="">Главное меню</a></div>
  <div class="ar"><a href="">Форум</a></div>
  <div class="ar"><a href="">Мобильная связь</a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Используем CSS для всех блоков `text-align: center` и `line-height: 110px;`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.hmenu {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #119EDA;
  height: 110px;
  line-height: 110px;
  text-align: center;
}
.ar {
  background-color: #119EDA;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  line-height: 44px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 44px;
  background: linear-gradient(rgb(10, 1, 255), rgb(8, 38, 119));
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-radius: 10pt;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hmenu">
  <div class="ar"><a href="">Главное меню</a>
  </div>
  <div class="ar"><a href="">Форум</a>
  </div>
  <div class="ar"><a href="">Мобильная связь</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

После чего получаем такую конструкцию :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Geyan http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators  ......идете в чат или мету и спрашивайте их, например

Comment: кнопки-меню мне понравились

Answer (score 3):

Решение через `display: inline-block;`:

```css
.ar {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  background-image:url(http://pro-okis.ru/file/pro-okis_ru/button/button2.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  min-width: 100px;
}

.hmenu {
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  color:white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family:verdana;
  font-size:14px;
}

body {
  background-color: #129EDB;
}
```

```html
<div class="hmenu">
  <div class="ar"><a href="">Главное меню</a></div>
  <div class="ar"><a href="">Форум</a></div>
  <div class="ar"><a href="">Мобильная связь</a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Решение на `display: flex`:

```css
.hmenu {
background-color:#119EDA;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
}

.hmenu a {
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
font: 1em sans-serif;
border-radius: 2em;
margin: 1em 0.3em;
padding: .5em 1em;
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, hsl(207, 85%, 57%) 15%, hsla(206, 93%, 33%, 1));
box-shadow: inset 0 -0.01em 0.2em 0.03em hsl(197, 57%, 67%),
            inset 0 0 1em hsla(207, 85%, 44%, 0.3),
            0 0.1em 0.3em -0.05em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
}
```

```html
<nav class="hmenu">
<a href="">Главное меню</a>
<a href="">Форум</a>
<a href="">Мобильная связь</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Спасибо Folant, четко порисовалась кнопка, Просто пытаюсь сверстать то, что сам нарисовал! Одновременно пытаюсь понять логику: вэб-дизайна и как это возможно технически сделать, ближе к реальности. Кнопку к примеру я рисовал в граф. редакторе.

Comment: Смотрите, конечно, сами, но кнопка, нарисованная в редакторе – это лишний запрос на сервер. Кнопки сделанные при помощи CSS-градиентов нисколько не оторваны от реальности, поскольку градиенты поддерживаются в современных браузерах. [http://caniuse.com/#search=linear-gradient](http://caniuse.com/#search=linear-gradient)

Comment: ну, замечательно, улучшили производительность, убрали лишний вес, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. Решение через Flexbox

```css
.container-fluid {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  
  display: flex;
  /* Центрируем по вертикали */
  align-items: center;
  /* Центрируем по горизонтали */
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5 text-center ">
      <div class="play-btn">
        <img src="http://elzol.lamusica.com/images/core/play.png" alt="Play">
        <p>Some Button</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### 2. Решение через псевдоэлемент с поддержкой IE 9

```css
.container-fluid {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Обертка */
.container-fluid:before {
   content: '';
   height: 100%;
   display: inline-block !important;
   vertical-align: middle;
}

/* Блок, который нужно выровнять */
.row {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5 text-center ">
      <div class="play-btn">
        <img src="http://elzol.lamusica.com/images/core/play.png" alt="Play">
        <p>Some Button</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### 3. Решение через абсолютное позиционирование

```css
.container-fluid {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.row{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5 text-center ">
      <div class="play-btn">
        <img src="http://elzol.lamusica.com/images/core/play.png" alt="Play">
        <p>Some Button</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

#### 4. Решение через line-height

```css
.container-fluid {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.row{
  line-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5 text-center ">
      <div class="play-btn">
        <img src="http://elzol.lamusica.com/images/core/play.png" alt="Play">
        <p>Some Button</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: по вертикали тоже наверное отцентрируется?

Comment: @Ep1demic, по вертикали центрируйте с помощью свойства line-height или padding. Но line-height  - более правильней.