# Вертикальное и горизонтальное центрирование элемента внутри блока

Tags: html, css, позиционирование

Есть несколько изображений разных размеров. При наведении на любое из них по центру должна появляться иконка лупы. Как её отцентрировать вертикально и горизонтально относительно изображения(повторюсь, каждое из них разных размеров)?

```
<div class="counter-item counter-item-1">
    <img src="img/counter-mini-1.png" alt="">
</div>

.counter-item-1
    margin: 26px 30px 30px 60px  
    position: relative

    &:before
        content: url('../img/round-add.png')
        position: absolute
        top: 0
        bottom: 0
        margin: 0 auto
        height: 54px
        width: 54px
        z-index: 10
```

Comment: А что именно не получается?

Comment: Добавил код. Не получается центрировать по вертикали и горизонтали. Получилось центрировать только горизонтально

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/610226/Нужно-центрировать-блок-a-внутри-div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
&:before
        content: url('../img/round-add.png')
        position: absolute
        top: calc((100% - 54px)/2)
        bottom: auto
left: calc((100% - 54px)/2)
        margin: 0 auto
        height: 54px
        width: 54px
        z-index: 10
```

есть в css некая ф-ция `calc()` , где можешь проводить математические расчеты для свойства

Comment: Для чего вы так усложнили жизнь? Достаточно было сделать отрицательный отступ используя `margin` на половину ширины объекта. Тем более, на `calc` будет ругаться валидатор.

Answer (score 3):

Очень хороший способ

```
before
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю еще один наиболее просто способ:

```
&:before
        content: url('../img/round-add.png')
        position: absolute
        top: 50%
        left: 50%;
        margin: -27px 0 0 -27px
        height: 54px
        width: 54px
        z-index: 10
```

Сперва переносим элемент ровно по центру, а затем смещаем его на половину его ширины и высоты.